# Arduino Simulator That Support Serial Input

Tags: arduino, simulator

Does somebody know if there is Arduino simulator that support serial input? I want to build some Arduino project that will read some serial input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use the free [Virtual Serial Port Emulator](http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) to tunnle a serial port. Now you can use this ports with [Virtual Breakboard](http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/MetroMain.htm).

You can find a good tutorial how to do it in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aT6E1OblR4A).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to VBB. For the virtual serial, I am using comm0comm with hub4comm to virtually connect those virtual serial lines.

Answer (score -1):

Try Simulator for Arduino [enter link description here](http://virtronics.com.au/Data/SetupFree.zip)

This has a Serial Monitor found under Tools in the menu and has some Options to read the real Serial data into the Serial Monitor